# How to convert Domino specific kyr file to pkcs12 on 64-bit windows

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, private-key

I need to get the private key out of my Domino kyr file, to import into another server. The key should be in the best case pkcs12 format.  I am aware of the [IKEYMAN](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21308138&cm_mc_uid=88336895938914309254675&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1455122078) tool by IBM. However, I cannot use that because I don't have access to a 32-bit windows XP. And unfortunately, only version 5 can understand the kyr format. 
It is a very strange conundrum. I hope somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download "kyrtool" [from IBM](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Lotus&product=ibm/Lotus/Lotus%20Domino&release=9.0.1.2&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=KYRTool_9x_ClientServer&includeSupersedes=0) and put it in the appropriate directory. This download contains versions for windows and linux.

Use the `show keys` command as described in [this link](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=B28BEC96CB4E1E6A85257DA1006B0545#mobileViewer) to show the private key in Base64 Format. You can then simply convert it into anything you need with e.g. Openssl.